# Regex how to find block of lines starting with "TcxGridDBBandedColumn", ending with "end" and not containing "Width" inside

Tags: regex

I am trying to find declarations of TcxGridDBBandedColumn in dfm files not containing Width parameter.
Every declaration starts with TcxGridDBBandedColumn and ends with end word. It can have many lines with many parameters inside the block but must not have line with Width parameter.

I already constructed regex to find a block:

```
^.*TcxGridDBBandedColumn(.|[\r\n])*?end
```

It looks to work fine, but I can't find how to add condition to exclude blocks with Width parameter specified.

Text example:

```
          object cxGrid_MainDBBandedTableView1SUMA: TcxGridDBBandedColumn
            Caption = 'Suma'
            DataBinding.FieldName = 'SUMA'
            RepositoryItem = Form_Resursai.cxEditRepository_MainCurrencyItem_DefKaina
            Position.BandIndex = 1
            Position.ColIndex = 7
            Position.RowIndex = 0
          end
          object cxGrid_MainDBBandedTableView1DBABSTRMAZMKAINA: TcxGridDBBandedColumn
            Caption = 'Ma'#382'm.Kaina'
            DataBinding.FieldName = 'MAZMKAINA'
            RepositoryItem = Form_Resursai.cxEditRepository_MainCurrencyItem_DefKaina
            Visible = False
            Width = 60
            Position.BandIndex = 0
            Position.ColIndex = 6
            Position.RowIndex = 0
          end
```

it should find only block:

```
  object cxGrid_MainDBBandedTableView1SUMA: TcxGridDBBandedColumn
    Caption = 'Suma'
    DataBinding.FieldName = 'SUMA'
    RepositoryItem = Form_Resursai.cxEditRepository_MainCurrencyItem_DefKaina
    Position.BandIndex = 1
    Position.ColIndex = 7
    Position.RowIndex = 0
  end
```

because it does not have Width.

Comment: You can make the match more specific by matching all the lines that do not start with the property or `Width =` or `end` If it always starts with `object` you can also use that in the pattern. `^[^\S\r\n]*object .*\bTcxGridDBBandedColumn(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:Width = |end$)).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*end$` https://regex101.com/r/noOVZH/1

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern that you tried, using `(.|[\r\n])*` is not a recommended way to match any character as there will be an alternation for every single character. Other options are using  `[\s\S]*?` or make the dot match a newline.

It is also repeating the capture group, and will only give you the captured value of the last iteration which will be a single char.

---

In this case, you can match the first line ending on `TcxGridDBBandedColumn`.

Then you can match all lines that do not start with either `end` or contain `Width =`

```
^[^\S\r\n]*object .*\bTcxGridDBBandedColumn(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:Width =|end$)).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*end$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*object .*\bTcxGridDBBandedColumn`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!` Match a newline and assert what is at the right is not

    - `[^\S\r\n]*(?:Width =|end$))` Match 0+ spaces and either `Width =` or `end`
  - `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all lines
- `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*end` match a newline, optional spaces and `end`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f17ynj/1)